# JupyterHub generic.oauthenticator: 500 Internal Server Error / 400 OAuth state missing from cookies

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub

I'm creating a **Dashboard** service where multiple users can access multiple notebook servers via `JupyterHub.`

Users log in using a separate **Authentication** service, and once in **Dashboard**, `JupyterHub` gets rendered inside an `<iframe>`.

I'm hosting `JupyterHub` in a `Kubernetes` cluster on GCP. These are the relevant portions of my `config.yaml`:

```
...
 # Changes the Jupyter's notebook headers to allow it to be displayed
 # inside of an iframe object.
 c.JupyterHub.tornado_settings = {
        "headers": {
          "Content-Security-Policy": "default-src *  data: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-dynamic'; script-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src * data: blob: ; style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';",
        }
      }
...
auth:
  type: custom
  custom:
    className: oauthenticator.generic.GenericOAuthenticator
    config:
      login_service: "OpenID" 
      client_id: "<client_id>"
      client_secret: "<client_secret>"
```

However, when I try to sign in just via my `JupyterHub` endpoint I get:

**500 Internal Server Error**

**logs:**

```
IwN2YyNzVhNTk0MzM0ZTM5YmIyZTdmZDQzY2U2ZDI3YyIsICJuZXh0X3VybCI6IG51bGx9&session_state=641fb9aca6490d2c3332871d72ee0639b3ed46b8a9f02c363ee8f7bf46f1c989.74e37d534296
cad45421019d1d442153', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='<>')

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1703, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/oauthenticator/oauth2.py", line 213, in get
        user = await self.login_user()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterhub/handlers/base.py", line 699, in login_user
        authenticated = await self.authenticate(data)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyterhub/auth.py", line 383, in get_authenticated_user
        authenticated = await maybe_future(self.authenticate(handler, data))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/oauthenticator/generic.py", line 136, in authenticate
        resp_json = json.loads(resp.body.decode('utf8', 'replace'))
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 5 column 1 (char 4)
```

I know it actually does redirect to the **Authentication Server** and the callback is correct. Even still when I attempt to access via **Dashboard**, within the `<iframe>` I get:

**400 OAuth state missing from cookies**

**logs:**

```
400 GET /hub/oauth_callback?code=d37de16a855a49dda94fb65c2c2c8ffa&state=eyJzdGF0ZV9pZCI6ICIwN2YyNzVhNTk0MzM0ZTM5Ym
IyZTdmZDQzY2U2ZDI3YyIsICJuZXh0X3VybCI6IG51bGx9&session_state=641fb9aca6490d2c3332871d72ee0639b3ed46b8a9f02c363ee8f7bf46f1c989.74e37d534296cad45421019d1d442153

OAuth state missing from cookies
```

For context: I previously used the Github OAuthenticator class and registered an OAuth app within Github and got `JupyterHub` to work fine. However, Github does not allow their apps to be used within an `<iframe>` so I had to go the generic route.

Point is, the setup was very similar and at least had `JupyterHub` working outside of **Dashboard**, so I'm really stumped on what else I could be missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this guy out, by any chance?

Comment: No sadly :( i got fired